# Ruby: Parsing arrays into categories, returning symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, methods, symbols

I am working on a ruby challenge requesting that I create a method that inputs an array of strings and separates the strings into 3 categories returned as symbols.  These symbols will return in an array.

- If the string contains the word "cat", then it returns the symbol
  `:cat`.
- If "dog", then it returns `:dog.`
- If the string does not contain "dog" or "cat" it returns the symbol
  `:none`

So far I have the following code but having trouble getting it to pass.

```
def pets (house)
  if house.include?/(?i:cat)/
    :cat = house
  elsif house.include?/(?i:dog)/
    :dog = house
  else
    :none = house
  end
end
```

`input = [ "We have a dog", "Cat running around!", "All dOgS bark", "Nothing to see here", nil ]`

It should return `[ :dog, :cat, :dog, :none, :none ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody went for the `case/when` approach, so here it is:

```
def pets(house)
  house.map do |item|
    case item
      when /dog/i
        :dog
      when /cat/i
        :cat
      else
        :none
    end
  end
end
```

`map` isn't that complicated: you use it whenever you have an array of *n* elements that you want to turn into *another* array of *n* elements.

I suspect people don't use `case/when` because they can't remember the syntax, but it's designed for just this situation, when you're testing one item against multiple alternatives. It's much cleaner than the if/elsif/elsif syntax, IMHO.

Comment: This worked out really well and was incredibly efficient. Thank you Todd!

Answer (score 1):

```
def pets (house)
  results = []
  house.each do |str|
    if str.to_s.downcase.include?('dog')
      results << :dog
    elsif str.to_s.downcase.include?('cat')
      results << :cat
    else
      results << :none
    end
  end
  return results
end
```

This works. And here's the above code, written in pseudo-code (plain english, following a code-like thought process) so you can see how I've come to the above solution.

```
def pets (house)
  # Define an empty array of results
  #
  # Now, loop over every element in the array 
  # that was passed in as a parameter:
  # 
  #    If that element contains 'dog',
  #        Then add :dog to the results array.
  #    If that element contains 'cat'
  #       Then add :cat to the results array
  #    Otherwise,
  #       Add :none to the results array
  #         
  # Finally, return the array of results.
end
```

There's a few concepts you seem to be not quite solid on - and I don't think I'll be able to explain them effectively here within a reasonable length. If at all possible, try to see if you can meet an experienced programmer face to face and go through the problem - it will be far easier than trying to battle it out yourself.

Comment: The other answer, which uses the 'map' method, is actually a more idiomatic, ruby-ish way to do it. However I think the map method is more complex to understand and requires understanding of more programming concepts. So, I've kept it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the Array#map method.

```
def pets (house)
    house.map do |animal|
        if animal.to_s.downcase.include?('cat')
            :cat
        elsif animal.to_s.downcase.include?('dog')
            :dog
        else
            :none
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a hash of matchers as keys, and results as values, as follows:

```
ma = [ :cat, :dog ]
input = [ "We have a dog", "Cat running around!", "All dOgS bark", "Nothing to see here", nil ]
input.map {|s| ma.reduce(:none) {|result,m| s.to_s =~ /#{m}/i && m || result } }
#  => [:dog, :cat, :dog, :none, :none]
```